# A semaphore with beginwait function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, semaphore

I'm writing a asynchronous library using begin/end, and I need to lock objects.

Currently, I'm doing this using semaphores, but calling `semaphore.WaitOne()` suspends the thread where it is called. I'd rather use something like BeginWait so it would return immediately and call the callback function when the semaphore is free.

Is there such an object in c#?

Comment: How about http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx? Not begin/callback, but task-based.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense. A thread can't be waiting on a semaphore and doing something else at the same time. Unless you're polling the semaphore periodically. Give us a little more information about what you're trying to do. I think you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @JimMischel The idea of an asychronous model is to not have threads doing blocking waits at all, not to create new threads just to have *them* do blocking waits for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is what I ended up with - maybe someone will find it useful:

```
class AsyncSemaphore
{
    public AsyncSemaphore(int counter, int maxCounter)
    {
        this.maxCounter = maxCounter;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    private int maxCounter, counter;

    class CallbackObject:IAsyncResult
    {
        private AsyncCallback callback;

        #region IAsyncResult Members

        public object AsyncState { get; set; }

        public System.Threading.WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get 
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously { get; set; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

        public AsyncCallback Callback
        {
            get { return callback; }
            set { callback = value; }
        }

        #endregion

    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<CallbackObject> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<CallbackObject>();

    public IAsyncResult BeginWait(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        if (callback==null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("callback","callback cannot be null");
        }
        var o=new CallbackObject();
        o.AsyncState = state;
        o.Callback = callback;
        bool execute = false;

        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.counter)>=0)
        {
            o.CompletedSynchronously= execute = true;
        }
        else
        {
            queue.Enqueue(o);
        }

        if (execute)
        {
            callback(o);
            o.IsCompleted = true;
        }

        return o;
    }

    public void EndWait(IAsyncResult r)
    {}

    public void Release()
    {
        CallbackObject execute = null;

        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref this.counter)<1)
        {
            if (!queue.TryDequeue(out execute))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (counter > maxCounter)
            {
                throw new SemaphoreFullException("Release was called too many times");
            } 
        }

        if (execute!=null)
        {
            execute.Callback(execute);
            execute.IsCompleted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `ConcurrentQueue` to avoid the need to lock around the queue, and you can use the `Interlocked` methods to manipulate `counter` to avoid needing locking surrounding it.  Between both of those you can actually move to an entirely lock-free model.

Comment: thanks! I didn't use concurrentqueue because I thought it used locks internally. awesome!

Comment: also, I'm not sure how to properly implement this code without creating race conditions with Interlocked: `if (counter>0)
                {
                    o.CompletedSynchronously= execute = true;
                    counter--;
                }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WaitAsync` method of `SemaphoreSlim` (.NET 4.5+) to get a `Task` that will be completed when the semaphore is next available.  You can add a continuation to that task to have a callback that will be called when the semaphore is active.