# Non-blocking waits using TPL / C# 5 / .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, nonblocking

I have some common code I need to refactor back to C# 5 (my original question said C# 4) / .NET 4.0 so that I can share it among more projects.  The biggest impact is not using `async` / `await` and switching back to TPL and using `ContinueWith()`.

Is there a way to accomplish non-blocking waits on synchronization objects without simulating this by throwing it into a background thread?  Timers I can use a `TaskCompletionSource` so I'm good there.

```
SemaphoreSlim mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

await mutex.WaitAsync(); // <-- how to get a Task that completes on mutex.Wait()
```

e.g.

```
mutex.WaitInATask().ContinueWith(...
```

**UPDATE** I have decided not to target C# 4.0 (but still target .NET 4.0 framework) because I'm more concerned about the assembly and not the source being able to be shared among projects.

I have decided to go with using Microsoft.Bcl.Async, Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx, target .NET 4.0 framework, and set build C# version to 5.0 (to support async/await).  This would likely require VS2015 to compile but the assembly (along with dependencies) would target .NET 4.0.

The additional benefit of this route is less code to refactor from `async`/`await` to `ContinueWith()` which should result in fewer bugs along the way...

Comment: I'm assuming that you also don't want to block "another" thread with the wait, i.e. you don't want to just spin a thread that sits in a wait state until the wait completes, right?

Comment: Can you use an external library like [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx)?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Exactly.  That's what I meant by "without simulating this by throwing it into a background thread".

Comment: How do you expect to release the mutex after you obtain it?

Comment: @MikeJansen The problem isn't with your consuming code, it's with the semaphore implementation in .NET 4. Unless it implements and exposes a non blocking API (a la `Begin*`, `End*`), which it seems like it doesn't, there's no way to use it without blocking at least one thread somewhere.

Comment: Someone actually had this problem and implemented a non blocking semaphore [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18597586/1726343). Just found this off google so I can't speak to the correctness/quality of code.

Comment: @YacoubMassad  Looking at Stephen's AsyncEx, I see he's referencing `"Microsoft.Bcl.Async` which may have what I'm looking for.  I will look further into that.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin following comments and links led to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx.  So it's looking like the solution is roll your own or have a buddy roll one for you.  Looks like this may be the solution.  An async mutex is mainly what I'm looking to solve.

Comment: Microsoft.Bcl.Async is exactly what you need. Make sure that you target .net 4.0 and using VS2012 or greater. that should make async await work.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My original requirement was C# 4.0 which does not support async/await, which this would not solve, but through my research and everybody's helpful input here, I am going to use .NET 4.0 / C# 5.0 since I mainly need to worry about assembly framework and not compiler (sharing binary not source with other projects).

Comment: @YacoubMassad I have decided to go with C# 5.0 (and .NET 4.0 Framework) so AsyncEx + Microsoft.Bcl.Async looks like it will be my solution.

Comment: In case anyone else is following this, I know in VS2015, not sure about earlier, you can go into Project Properties / Build / Advanced and set the C#  version that you are supporting.  Make sure to get the latest VS2015 update; there were issues in the RTM with this.

Comment: @MikeJansen If you've found a way to solve the problem described in the question, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I plan to do just that once I know it's actually working.  I've converted my library but I need to test it in a couple projects before I know if this is actually a solution. Should be early this coming week. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through research inspired by comments on the question, I have come up with the following answer:

First of all, I dropped the requirement of the compiler to be C# 4.0.  This means that the binary will still be compatible with .NET 4.0 Framework, but the source code will require a compiler that supports C# 5.0 (e.g. Visual Studio 2015).  I can share binaries with legacy projects but not source code.

The cleanest way to have non-blocking waits in .NET 4.0 Framework is:

1. Create a Class Library project that targets .NET 4.0 Framework (do this with a fresh project to avoid references not getting updated properly when you switch the framework version after creation)
2. Set C# version (in VS 2015, Project Properties / Build / Advanced) to 5.0.  This enables the async/await syntax, meaning I don't need to re-code all my async/await into ugly, complex .ContinueWith() nests and hacks.
3. Add NuGet packages Nito.AsyncEx and Microsoft.Bcl.Async (the latter comes with the former, but I found I needed to include a newer version of Microsoft.Bcl.Async than was required as a dependency by Nito.AsyncEx, so I added Microsoft.Bcl.Async first).
4. Convert any synchronization object using a WaitAsync() to use the AsyncEx version, e.g. SemaphoreSlim => AsyncSemaphore.

At the very least, this allows me to re-use some valuable functionality by referencing the binaries in our older .NET 4.0 projects that can't currently be upgraded for various reasons.

Comment: 4.0 is no longer supported. It's either 3.5 or 4.5.2+. You *shouldn't* target 4.0 if you're concerned about the assembly. In fact, it's almost guaranteed that wherever you deploy it will be 4.5.2 at least - 4.5+ is a binary replacement for 4.0, delivered via Windows Update. Even in servers -  TLS1.2 was added in 4.5.2 so you can expect other devs have already requested the upgrade to the 4.5.2 runtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't have the luxury of dictating that we don't support .NET 4.0 Framework in the company I work for.  In fact, we still have to support Windows XP in certain scenarios (which I believe is where the .NET 4.0 requirement is coming in).  I'm the guy pushing us forward many times.  But I have this reality to deal with. Much to the dismay of many developers, companies often still support OS's and frameworks that manufacturers have abandoned. Given this situation, this solution works if I want to share functionality with those older projects.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain to management that the company is liable for using broken encryption? That's one reason a *lot* of shops switched to 4.5.2 - and the fact that the Web Services (banks, payment gateways, airlines, merchants etc) they used disabled all less than TLS 1.1. There are real reasons why you *can't* get stuck on an unsupported platform

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I appreciate your input.  It is all good.  I have only so much time to fight regarding security, supportability, maintainablity, extensibility, etc., etc.  If I were 10 years younger I might add this one to my active battles :)  I did forward your comments on to one of the managers that has the product with this requirement though.